# __set in constructor?

Tags: php, constructor, magic-methods

Is the magic method __set called when setting properties in __construct?

```
class MyClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->property = 'something';
    }
    public function __set($name,$value)
    {
        $this->{$name} = ($name == 'property')?'other value':$value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd guess so, would not be hard to run that code and see for yourself?

Comment: Why don't you just instantiate the class (no other method calls) and put an echo into the __set, that should tell you.

Comment: It was a sudden doubt i had, I cant test it now but it seemed so simple that I thought php sages over here would know without a doubt.

Comment: I take it you are not aware of sites like codepad? If you are able to post this question, you are also able to test the code :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly legal to do. From the manual:

> __set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties.

It does not matter if it is done from the constructor.

so invoking:

```
$x = new MyClass();
var_dump($x);
```

will result in:

```
object(MyClass)#1 (1) { ["property"]=> string(11) "other value" }
```